# Restarting Windows 2003 File Server and Network Drives

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-xp, file-server

If I restart a Windows 2003 file server, will XP clients that have network drives mapped to a location on that server need to re-map (or restart) the network drives?

Comment: Actually, now that I think about the reason I vaguely remember doing this was maybe because the time got off the file server...Confirmation would still be nice though

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They won't have to remap.  The connections should be re-established behind-the-scenes the next time a user tries to browse that drive.  If they have an explorer window open at the time of the reboot then they'll get a message that the location is no longer available until the connection is re-established.

Note, though, that if they have files open on those shares they might have problems depending on what apps they are using for them.

Answer (score 1):

I had to do this recently. Restarted the server, but the program that the user was working with as not able to reconnect to the 'disconnected' drive. Had to open up explorer and open the 'disconnected' drive close it, then the program would start using it.